# How to show wind direction and speed in geoserver?

Tags: postgresql, leaflet, gis

I am utilizing a technology stack comprising PostgreSQL,Postgis, GeoServer, and Node.js to visualize wind direction and speed on the client side. The visualization is facilitated by the Leaflet library, specifically the leaflet-velocity plugin [leaflet-velocity librery](https://github.com/onaci/leaflet-velocity). The data, retrieved through APIs, undergoes modification on the server side before being sent to the client. In this process, I am faced with the challenge of understanding and implementing the concepts of dy/dx and ny/nx. The sample data consists of columns named geom, lat, long, wind_direction, and wind_speed, with corresponding values like (0101000020E6100000AE62F19BC2F25140D788601C5CC8414, lat_value, long_value, 28, 8). With over 1400 data points, my goal is to transform the data in a way that aligns with the requirements of the Leaflet-velocity library. This involves calculating dy/dx and ny/nx, crucial parameters for configuring the library on the frontend.
How i calculate the dy/dx and ny/nx?

Here is frontend librery data format

```
[
{
        "header": {
            "parameterUnit": "m.s-1",
            "parameterNumber": 2,
            "dx": 1,
            "dy": 1,
            "parameterNumberName": "eastward_wind",
            "la1": 37.08508,
            "la2": 23.694683,
            "parameterCategory": 2,
            "lo1": 60.878597,
            "lo2": 77.691317,
            "nx": ?,
            "ny": ?,
            "refTime": "2023-12-03 00:00:00"
        },
    "data":[
7.063580742871416,
            -2.0521208599540124,
            2.150207697271797,
            1.2474701449065515,
            0.5229344564859473,
            0.10471443862369878,
            0.1744974835125064,
            -3.108583845827883,
            -3.9780875814730936,
    .
    .
    .]
    },
{
        "header": {
            "parameterUnit": "m.s-1",
            "parameterNumber": 2,
            "dx": 1,
            "dy": 1,
            "parameterNumberName": "eastward_wind",
            "la1": 37.08508,
            "la2": 23.694683,
            "parameterCategory": 2,
            "lo1": 60.878597,
            "lo2": 77.691317,
            "nx": ?,
            "ny": ?,
            "refTime": "2023-12-03 00:00:00"
        },
    "data":[3.7557725022871264,
            5.638155724715451,
            -5.6014825589832125,
            -5.868885604402835,
            -5.977168188550474,
            -5.999086170938348,
.
.
.
]
    }


]
```

Comment: @TimRoberts my question is how i calculate the dy/dx and ny/nx in my case? what does it mean?